# When is the following preorder on the set of central elements of order 2 a total preorder?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $G$ be a finite 2-group. Denote by $S$ the set of central elements of $G$ of order exactly $2$. The relation $a\leq b$ iff there is an endomorphism of $G$ sending $b$ to $a$ defines a preorder on $S$. This preorder is readily seen not to be a partial order (consider the Klein four-group). For which 2-groups is this preorder total?

It is true for abelian $G$. It is true for $G$ of maximal class (because there is a unique central element of order exactly 2). For groups of intermediate nilpotency class, it can be either true or false, e.g. the property is not true for the group with GAP ID [16, 3] but it is true for the group with GAP ID [16, 4]. It can be seen using the following Sage code

```
    g = gap.SmallGroup(InsertGAPIDhere);
    checker1 = True;        
    list1 = gap.AsList(gap.Centre(g));
    list2 = gap.AsList(gap.AllEndomorphisms(g));
    for a in list1:
        for b in list1:
            if gap.Order(a) == 2 and gap.Order(b) == 2:
                checker2 = False;
                for m in list2:
                    if gap.Image(m, a) == b or gap.Image(m, b) == a:
                        checker2 = True;
                checker1 = (checker1 and checker2);
    print(checker1);
```

Comment: "For which 2-groups is this preorder total?" -- total? (What does it mean in this context)?

Comment: @WlodAA A preorder is called total if the canonical partially ordered quotient is totally ( = linearly) ordered, i.e., every two elements are comparable. (So Mark Sapir seems to be saying that "central" in the OP's definition of $S$ doesn't matter.)

Comment: These are precisely the groups where for any two central involutions there is an endomorphism taking one of them to the other.

Comment: @MarkSapir I was hoping for something less tautological (but maybe it is overly optimistic).

Comment: It is too optimistic.